# Convert ada.Containers.Vector to array

Tags: arrays, vector, ada

If I have defined an array type like

```
type Integer_Array is array(Natural range <>) of Integer;
```

and also use package Ada.Containers.Vectors as

```
package Integer_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(
    Element_Type => Integer,
    Index_Type => Natural);
use Integer_Vectors;
```

How can I implement the following function?

```
function To_Integer_Array(V : Integer_Vectors.Vector) return Integer_Array;
```

---

**What I have so far**

Conceptually, it seems really easy:

1. Declare *Temp_Arr* as *Integer_Array* with capacity of *V.Length*
2. Iterate over *V* and copy all elements to *Temp_Arr*
3. Return *Temp_Arr*

Step 1. is giving me headaches though. I have tried:

```
function To_Integer_Array(V: Integer_Vectors.Vector) return Integer_Array is
    Temp_Arr: Integer_Array(1..V.Length);
begin
    -- Todo: copy values here
    return Temp_Arr;
end To_Integer_Array;
```

This will throw

```
expected type "Standard.Integer"
found type "Ada.Containers.Count_Type"
```

While the error absolutely makes sense, I am unsure as to how I might solve it.

Is there a way to cast Ada.Containers.Count_Type to Standard.Integer?
Would there be another way to create an Integer_Array from Integer_Vector?

Comment: `Integer(V.Length)` or better, `Natural(V.Length)`

Comment: That was quick thanks. Is that safe for every Count_Type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but fi it's unsafe I'd expect the compiler to tell me. All the type conversion means is "yes I meant to do that".

Comment: Just wasn't sure if there would be any unexpected reason for *Natural(V.Length)* to fail, because I didn't know the value range of *Count_Type*. But I guess a vector will always have *Natural* length.

Comment: It's still safe because, unless you're compiling with checks suppressed(!), something like `Byte(V.Length)` would raise a Constraint_Error exception pointing at the problem instead of trashing your data (or someone else's). (!)GNAT does suppress some checks by default. Add `-gnato -fstack-check` to the command for full Ada compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Brian the declaration now works. The correct implementation for my function looks like this:

```
function To_Integer_Array(V: Integer_Vector) return Integer_Array is
    Temp_Arr: Integer_Array(1..Natural(V.Length));
begin
    for I in Temp_Arr'Range loop
        Temp_Arr(I) := V.Element(I);
    end loop;
    return Temp_Arr;
end To_Integer_Array;
```